# Migration of seeds between continents

Tags: biology, extinction, currents, wind

In my story, life is disappearing from every continent of the world, from small animals to great sequoia trees, except for bacteria, of course, and marine life. except for one continent: Antarctica.

Suppose that after this mysterious extinction of life, Antarctica melted most of it and revealed (albeit mostly naive science fiction) many seeds from different eras, these seeds grew in the soil until the icy continent turned into Paradise (Don't really focus on the reality of this),**Is there any chance that the seeds will move from Antarctica to other continents within a period of 50 million years, assuming that the wind patterns do not change and the positions of the continents do not change?** As well as the possibility of its growth into plants and forests that restore vegetation cover to the earth?

Comment: FYI: without animals (specifically birds), most seeds would not disperse far by air (spores can though).  However, many (most?) seeds float, so they can disperse by sea, river, etc.,

Comment: 50 million years is also plenty of time for continental drift to play a role.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks very likely.

[This](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/sciadv.abd1273) is a dispersion chart of Antarctic icebergs

[image]

As you can see while they are carried by ocean currents they easily reach latitudes where land is present: it can be Terra del Fuego, Malvinas/Falkland or New Zealand, but it's basically just a matter of time before some seeds, carried by water, touches land.

And 50 million years is a long period of time, so it will happen sooner or later.

Comment: Unlikely that an Antarctica free of ice is compatible with the same pattern of ocean currents as today and unlikely that the conformation of islands/continents will be the same over 50My but, admitting the ocean currents don't vanish at all, yes there will be other currents to carry Antarctican seed on other continents.

Comment: On the other hand, many (most) seeds do float, so sea currents are still a viable vector.